# how to check if a user started a bot in telegram or not?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm developing a bot in telegram , here is my problem:
I have some posts in my channel which some inline_keyboards are attached to them. when a user press the button , next events happen in a bot and some messages show to a user. if user has been started the bot before , there is no problem , if not I have error. how should I check the user is member of my bot or not to handle this problem???

Comment: Can you better explain what this buttons does and if they are buttons with link, show_alert etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check if bot can talk to user or not without send message.

You can use url with `https://t.me/Bot?start=some_data` format, and you will receive `/start some_data`, please try [this link](https://t.me/RawDataBot?start=Hello) yourself.

Answer (score 2):

try to use sendMessage() API and send a message to user. After that telegram will response a status tell you whether success or not.

if started bot receive receive is ok, 
if not started bot receive is nothing.

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":9999,"from":{"id":00000000,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"mybot","username":"mybot"}}}
```

like that, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is that if a lot of users do the same, telegram starts to throttle your callbacks :( ... it would be so much easier if you could just read that information somewhere...